# I am facing error on Next.js project deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am deploying my next project on vercel or netlify, but I am facing this error

> 9:46:29 AM: Failed during stage "Install dependencies": dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/styles@5.15.14
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!   react@"^18" from the root project
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotionreact@11.11.4
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.11.4" from the root project
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.11.0" from the root project
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!   13 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.15.14
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"^5.15.14" from the root project
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.15.14
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/styles
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!     @mui/styles@"^5.15.14" from the root project
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR!
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! For a full report see:
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-03-21T04_46_29_006Z-eresolve-report.txt
>
> 9:46:29 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-03-21T04_46_29_006Z-debug-0.log
>
> 9:46:29 AM: Error during npm install

my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "postman-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.15.14",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "next": "14.1.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```